# Unable to Update rows of DataGridView from DB Query

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

i'm having problems with updating a DataGridView to rows from data from a database. The code I have is as followed:

```
    public Array ClientSearch(string Argument, string SearchType)
    {
        Connection.Open();
        string QueryStr = "SELECT ClientName,PostCode,ContactNo FROM ClientSearch WHERE "+SearchType+" LIKE %"+Argument+"%";



        SqlCommand Query = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, Connection);

        SqlDataReader ExecuteQuery = Query.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable ResultSet = new DataTable();

        ResultSet.Load(ExecuteQuery);
        Connection.Close();
        if (ResultSet.Rows.Count.Equals(0))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {

            // Single-dimensional array (strings).
            System.Collections.ArrayList Results = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
            while (ExecuteQuery.Read())
            {
                Results.Add(ExecuteQuery.GetString(0));
            }

            return Results.ToArray();

        }
    }
```

And the method is invoked by:

```
    private void SearchBy_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLCmdSet Database = new SQLCmdSet();
        string Param = "";
        if (this.ByName.Checked.Equals(true))
        {
            Param = "ClientName";
        }
        if (this.ByPostCode.Checked.Equals(true))
        {
            Param = "PostCode";
        }
        Array Array = Database.ClientSearch(this.SearchBy.Text, Param);

        foreach (string Element in Array)
        {
            this.ClientInfor.Rows.Add(Element);
        }
    }
```

The Grid its self has 3 Columns named:

> ClientName
>
> PostCode
>
> ContactNo

I've tried the following link to assist http://www.rhyous.com/2010/05/28/how-to-query-a-database-in-csharp/ and tried manually modifying to return to the method which would handle the addition of rows. This provided no avail, then I searched some stackoverflow URLs to find the method which uses a while loop on `ExecuteQuery.Read()` but this also provided no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was quite simple after further research:

I changed the Querying Method to return a DataTable by:

```
 public DataTable ClientSearch(string Argument, string SearchType)
        {
            Connection.Open();
            string QueryStr = "SELECT ClientName,PostCode,ContactNo FROM Clients WHERE " + SearchType + " LIKE '%" + Argument + "%'";
            DataTable DataT = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter SQLDA = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryStr, Connection);
            SQLDA.Fill(DataT);
            return DataT;

        }
```

and also opened the connection to the Database, and the modified Searchby text box method has been changed to the following:

```
    private void SearchBy_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLCmdSet Database = new SQLCmdSet();
        string Param = "";
        if (this.ByName.Checked)
        {
            Param = "ClientName";
        }
        if (this.ByPostCode.Checked)
        {
            Param = "PostCode";
        }

        this.ClientInfor.DataSource = Database.ClientSearch(this.SearchBy.Text,Param);

    }
```